# How to handle bad trailing data in input?

Tags: python, antlr4

I am attempting to understand how ANTLR4 handles errors in a Python environment. My final code needs to detect and report any data in the file that is not valid regardless of where it appears. As part of this effort I am using the examples in the [py3antlr4book](https://github.com/jszheng/py3antlr4book) to try some basic scenarios. Specifically, I used the example in the 01-Hello directory and tried two different input files with bogus entries added:

### [Hello.g4](https://github.com/jszheng/py3antlr4book/blob/master/01-Hello/Hello.g4)

```
grammar Hello;            // Define a grammar called Hello
r  : 'hello' ID ;         // match keyword hello followed by an identifier
ID : [a-z]+ ;             // match lower-case identifiers
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines, \r (Windows)
```

### bogus_first.txt

```
bogus
hello world
```

### Output

```
line 1:0 extraneous input 'bogus' expecting 'hello'
(r bogus hello world)
```

## bogus_last.txt

```
hello world
bogus
```

### Output

```
(r hello world)
```

The output from bogus_first.txt makes a lot of sense to me. It errored, and it indicated where the error is. The output from bogus_last.txt didn't error and didn't indicate there was some sort of bad input in the data. This is surprising to me at least. I tried using this [article's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224980/python-2-7-antlr4-make-antlr-throw-exceptions-on-invalid-input) suggestion of adding an ErrorListener, but that didn't seem to catch the bogus entry. I also tried adding an ErrorStrategy, but that didn't seem to catch the bogus entry either.

Below is the code I used to implement the ErrorListener and ErrorStrategy. The inErrorRecoveryMode didn't seem to be at the line I wanted, but I am not really sure if I am just printing out the correct data or not.

What do I need to change about my testbench in order to be able to error on something like the example bogus_last.txt?

## test_hello.py

```
import sys
from antlr4 import *
from HelloLexer import HelloLexer
from HelloParser import HelloParser
from antlr4.error.ErrorListener import ErrorListener
from antlr4.error.ErrorStrategy import DefaultErrorStrategy

class MyErrorListener( ErrorListener ):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def syntaxError(self, recognizer, offendingSymbol, line, column, msg, e):
        raise Exception("Oh no!!")

    def reportAmbiguity(self, recognizer, dfa, startIndex, stopIndex, exact, ambigAlts, configs):
        raise Exception("Oh no!!")

    def reportAttemptingFullContext(self, recognizer, dfa, startIndex, stopIndex, conflictingAlts, configs):
        raise Exception("Oh no!!")

    def reportContextSensitivity(self, recognizer, dfa, startIndex, stopIndex, prediction, configs):
        raise Exception("Oh no!!")

class MyErrorStrategy(DefaultErrorStrategy):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def reset(self, parser):
        raise Exception("Oh no!!")

    def recoverInline(self, parser):
        raise Exception("Oh no!!")

    def recover(self, parser, excp):
        raise Exception("Oh no!!")

    def sync(self, parser):
        raise Exception("Oh no!!")

    def inErrorRecoveryMode(self, parser):
        ctx = parser._ctx
        print(self.lastErrorIndex)
        return super().inErrorRecoveryMode(parser)

    def reportError(self, parser, excp):
        raise Exception("Oh no!!")


def main(argv):
    input = FileStream(argv[1])
    lexer = HelloLexer(input)
    stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = HelloParser(stream)
    parser.addErrorListener( MyErrorListener() )
    parser._errHandler = MyErrorStrategy()
    tree = parser.r()
    print(tree.toStringTree(recog=parser))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that:

```
hello world
bogus
```

didn't produce an error is because the parser successfully parses `hello world` using the production `r  : 'hello' ID ;` and then stops. You did not tell the parser to consume all the tokens from the token stream. If you want to force the parser to do that, add the `EOF` token to the end of your rule:

```
r  : 'hello' ID EOF;
```

Then input like:

```
hello world
bogus
```

will produce an error. But this error is only printed to your `stderr` stream and the parser tries to recover and continue parsing. To let it fail, do something like this:

```py
import antlr4
from antlr4.error.ErrorListener import ErrorListener

from HelloLexer import HelloLexer
from HelloParser import HelloParser


class BailOnErrorListener(ErrorListener):
    def syntaxError(self, recognizer, offending_symbol, line: int, column: int, msg, error):
        raise RuntimeError(f'msg: {msg}')


def main(src):
    lexer = HelloLexer(antlr4.InputStream(src))
    parser = HelloParser(antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer))
    parser.removeErrorListeners()
    parser.addErrorListener(BailOnErrorListener())
    tree = parser.r()
    print(tree.toStringTree(recog=parser))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    src = "hello world\nbogus"
    main(src)
```

and then invoking `parser.r()` will fail:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
RuntimeError: msg: extraneous input 'bogus' expecting <EOF>
```